# chrome v73 css flex overflow issue

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexbox

Are there any changes in CSS specks or is this a chrome issue with overflowing flex box containers.

In version 71 of chrome everything works as expected:
[image]

And in version 73 of chrome scrolls and overflows are broken:
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm seeing this in a ReactJS project too, as of Chrome v73. This may solve your problem: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6736527476391936

Comment: You may also want to try setting height to 100% on parent divs/containers.

Comment: I read about min-height: 0 that needs to be placed on every column oriented flex container, because if it is not set to zero, it defaults to auto which actually  takes the height of the content. I have many nested flex containers in my app, so I will need time to test this. When I am done I will write here if this solved my problem.